# Repeat a input variable

Tags: python

I’m working on my AP create task. I made a shopping cart where if you type "shop" in the code, a prompt pops up that allows you to add a item to cart.

###### Code:

```
def shop():
  if user_1 == "shop":
    print("\n")
    shop_1 = input("type a item to add to cart")
    shopping_list.append(shop_1)
```

Right now, it works so that when you enter an item and press enter, it basically stops the code. How would I make it so it repeats and u can keep typing variables to add to the list?

Comment: make a function that gets input from the user! then call it after `shopping_list.append(shop_1)` ! You can customize the function as you wish, you can edd `exit` keyword to it for exiting the program! `if input== "exit": exit()`. this way, just after entering `exit` the code stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way to prevent stopping the code:

```
shopping_list = []

def get_input():
    """
    This function just get user Input
    """
    inp = input("Enter input:\n")
    return inp

def show_list():
    """
    This function just prints the shopping list
    """
    print(f"shopping list is as follow : {shopping_list}")

def shop():
    inp = get_input()
    if inp =="shop":    
        print("\n")
        shop_1 = input("type a item to add to cart")
        shopping_list.append(shop_1)
    
        # Here is what you want, this line calls the shop function to get new input from the user and check its value again.
        shop()


    elif inp == "show":
        show_list()
        shop()

    elif inp =="exit":
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do a while loop.
So that it will keep asking until you are done.

```
still_shoping = True

while still_shoping:
def shop():
    if user_1 == "shop":
        print("\n")
        shop_1 = input("type a item to add to cart. or type 'done' if you wanna go to the next step")
        if shop_1 == "done":
            still_shoping = False
        else:
            shopping_list.append(shop_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside a infinite loop.

```
while True:
    #your code
```

If you want to stop running the loop at a place, you may change your condition to this

```
while ((input_variable := input())!= "stop"):
```

Comment: ^If you're using a recent version of Python - the walrus operator came with 3.8 or 3.9.